# VB Console - how to get multiple input in the same line, split and store to list

Tags: windows, vb.net, console

Say i want to get all the numbers a user inputs in the console.

> 15,30 45

then I want to then split the 'string' of numbers into different substrings and store it into an array of string or list of type string. Also i want to get the max min avg and total.

1. Should i store the substring in a array or generic list? I prefer to store it in a list so that i can get the avg and total using list.avg and list.sum
2. In order to get max min avg and sum, should i convert each element into an integer or convert the whole list to another type? If so, how do i convert?

**EDIT: Is there any way to let the user edit the numbers if somehow he mixed a letter or symbol?**

Comment: What is the desired result, `15,30,45` or `15.30,45`?

Comment: element 0=15, 1=30, 2=45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can also get the avarage or sum if its a `int[]` instead of `List<int>` since `Enumerable.Sum` or `Enumerable.Average` takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. So the decision depends on if you need to modify the collection afterwards. Do you want to add or remove items from it later? Then use a generic `List<T>`.

```
string input = "15,30 45";
int i = int.MinValue;
List<int> result = input.Split(new[]{' ', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(str => int.TryParse(str, out i))
    .Select(str => i)
    .ToList();
double avg = result.Average();
int sum =  result.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this code

```
void Main()
{
    double temp;
    List<double> input = new List<double>();
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
    foreach(string p in parts)
    {
        if(double.TryParse(p, out temp))
            input.Add(temp);
    }

    double sum = input.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Here I get the input from the Console.ReadLine and split the line at the space separator. Every line subpart is converted to a double value (only if it is possible to convert to a double according to your locale settings) and added to a `List<double>` . At this point is really simple to obtain the information you need (IEnumerable.Sum, IEnumerable.Average, etc..)